# Responsive design: Is it better to hide or to change position of elements?

Tags: html, css, position, responsive-design

I have the following dilemma with two elements (menu items) that I need to move in a responsive design (it's only two variations for now, let's say one for over 750px width and another for under 750px wide):

Should I have two separate html blocks, one for each variation, and hide/show them depending on the devise size?

Or should I have only one html block and css styles that play with positions? This last option is kind of complicated with the design I'm planning, so the real question might be: is it too bad to have two different html blocks? The page will have javascript and ajax interaction, although I'm not sure to what extent. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, **polling**, or **extended discussion**.

Comment: It's more a matter of actual efficiency advantages (and they have been named) than opinions. It's better not to have different html blocks because it goes against accessibility, usability and programming rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stating whether it's "bad" is subjective and relative to what your goals are. From an accessibility standpoint, it's not ideal to have the same markup appear twice and just toggle hiding one or the other, but without knowing more about the particulars of your design, it's difficult to state with any certainty that it should or shouldn't be done a particular way. I would say that, in general, it shouldn't be that difficult because your markup shouldn't be structured with the layout or design in mind.

Comment: You are right about the accessibility and I can't believe I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Some rules of thumb I try to keep in mind for responsive designs:

- Keep it in the CSS as much as possible. [You can control so much solely by changing the CSS](http://www.csszengarden.com/) if your markup is sane. Corollary: don't pollute the HTML any more than you have to.
- Minimize the amount of data you send to the browser. Mobile data connections are slow, unreliable, and increasingly data-capped and throttled.
- The page should be *reasonably* sane without any CSS. Think about what Googlebot or a screen reader will "see." This should be true of *any* website, though that doesn't mean it often *is.*

Based on those, I'd say **don't use two separate HTML blocks.**

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how you're altering the designs. If it's just a case that the designs have different widths, heights, images etc. then having the multiple HTML would violate one of the standard rules of programming:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

However if the design differences are structural then having different HTML would be fine rather than trying to force it through CSS.

btw One advantage of doing it through CSS if possible would be that when your boss (inevitably) comes along and asks for a third version that specifically designed for devices that are 1024px or wider. If you'd gone for the CSS route it would be a few minutes of work to add another set of sizes. With the HTML route you'd be locked in to making everything even more complicated.

Comment: The block changes in style, which is not difficult to achieve, but it also changes position inside a fluid div. It's a 6-stage design so I'll have to tweak it a few times. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to my opinion, its not a good idea to use two html blocks... It may cause confusion in deciding which one to hide and which to show... But without knowing about your design and purpose, it cant be decided... But In general try to avoid two or more html blocks...